# Break the loop in Bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, loops, while-loop

I'd like to check if DB cluster in AWS became available after restore and continue with rest part of the script:
So this is the Bash script to check:

```
echo "Checking if $TARGET_CLUSTER_ID-test reached Available state"
while [ "${cluster_available}" != "available" ]
do
    echo "Waiting for $TARGET_CLUSTER_ID-test to enter Available state"
    aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_ID-test --query 'DBClusters[0].[Status]' --output text
    cluster_available="$?"
    CLUSTER_STATUS=$(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier $TARGET_CLUSTER_ID-test --query 'DBClusters[0].[Status]' --output text)
    echo "$TARGET_CLUSTER_ID-test instance state is: ${CLUSTER_STATUS}"
done
```

Unfortunately it doesn't stop when cluster is available. What it is doing instead is keep flooding terminal with:

```
cluster-name instance state is: 
Waiting for cluster-name-test to enter Available state
available
cluster-name-test instance state is: 
Waiting for cluster-name-test to enter Available state
available
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always good practice to run bash script in debug mode where one wants to test the equality of string and put some sleep in while-loop doing remote calls. So this is how I modified your script and I am able to verify RDS status.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -x
echo "Checking if $TARGET_CLUSTER_ID-test reached Available state"
time=0
CLUSTER="adiltest-ejabberd-db"
while [ "${cluster_available}" != "available" ]
do
    echo "checking RDS availiblity"
    status=$(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier "${CLUSTER}" --query 'DBClusters[0].[Status]' --output text)
    if [ $status == "available" ];then 
    echo "RDS is availble"
    cluster_available="available"
    else
    echo "Waiting for $CLUSTER to enter Available state"
    sleep=2
    echo $time  "Seconds Elapsed"
    time=$((time + 2))
    fi
done
```

Here is the output

[image]

**update:** Add an elapsed time

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You set `cluster_available` to a number (the exit code of `aws`), but test it against the string *available*. Of course this will always be unequal.

I don't know, how aws signals availability, but probably testing `$CLUSTER_STATUS` would be a better idea.

Also, it doesn't make sense to execute the `aws rds describe-db-clusters` twice within a single loop iteration.